# Calculating power for a survey to compare different metrics

Tags: sampling, sample-size, survey, statistical-power

I am currently planning a survey. The data will be used to test which of three metrics best captures some "true" underlying characteristic of the respondents. Getting data on the "true" underlying characteristic is costly, so I want a simplified metric that best approximates the "true" measure.

For the current survey, I am gathering four data points for each observation.

1) metric 1

2) metric 2

3) metric 3

4) the "true" underlying characteristic

In the future, I won't have data on the "true" characteristic, so I will rely on one metric. For future work we will collect just the data for the "best" metric.

I am not clear about what effect size (aka difference in prevalence of indicator) to use to calculate sample size. Specifically, the hypothesized effect that I seek to identify, I believe is the difference between the metrics in their correlation to the true measure. For instance, if metric 1 has correlation 0.7 with the true characteristic, and metric 2 has a correlation 0.9, then the "effect size" of switching from metric 1 to metric 2 is 0.2.

Am I on track?